# How to send a file for single POST parameter with CURL?

Tags: curl, http

I want to send `myfile.json` for one POST parameter while specifying explicit value for another parameter with CURL. Is it possible?

Something like `POST a=value1&b=<load and encode from my file.json>`

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql\
     --data-urlencode "query@query.sparql" \
     --data-urlencode "format=csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation you will find this syntax:

```
curl -XPOST -d b=@/path/postbody.json
```